# Should I have asked my question on SO, instead of security.SE?

Tags: discussion

I just today asked a question on the Information Security SE site (https://security.stackexchange.com/q/165841/153267). I'm now wondering if I should have asked it on SO. I'm a programmer, am usually on SO, and I need the answer to this question for a program I'm writing, but I thought it belongs in Information Security.

Is it a question that's (also) appropriate on SO? If so, should I ask it on SO? Where does is really belong?

**Edit:** I applied for migration to SO, and it has been migrated. Thanks everybody.

Comment: The topic of the question is what determines where it should be asked, not who you are nor what the big plan is. I'm an economist, and I'm not asking R programming questions on [economics.se].

Comment: It belongs wherever it is considered an on-topic, quality question. If the answer to that is multiple SE sites then ask it wherever you are most likely to get a good answer. (Ex: A question about using the Arc GIS JS API would be on topic here but I'd ask it at the GIS Stack Exchange instead.)

Comment: Okay, so how does migrating a question work? (I have a suspicion SO will get me an answer quicker.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that there's often some degree of overlap between sites, so questions could be on topic for several sites. I'm not familiar with Information Security SE's guidelines are, to be honest, but the question you link to is definitely on topic here.

This actually came up on Literature SE awhile back (see [my Meta post there](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-to-decide-where-to-post-questions-that-are-on-topic-for-multiple-sites)), where there are sometimes topics that are on-topic for several sites. For example, questions about the *Chronicles of Narnia* (C. S. Lewis) series appear on Literature SE, Christianity SE, and Science Fiction SE. Similarly, *Lord of the Rings* questions are on topic both on Literature SE and on Science Fiction SE. To quote from the accepted answer by @Mithrandir:

> As an active member of both SFF and Lit, I faced this decision also. Lately, I've been more active here, because this is a fledgling site and needs lots of good questions. SFF is a well established site, with lots of questions and answers and people, while we're just getting started. So for now, I've been mostly posting questions on Lit. However, we're no longer in private beta, so that's not as important - it's still important, but less so.
>
> However, **I'd recommend posting it on the site where you feel you will get the best answer.** Each site is different, has different expectations and norms, a different style... **It all depends on what kind of answer you are expecting.**

I think that this advice applies here as well.

**TL;DR** Questions can be on topic for multiple sites. If your question is, think about what kind of answer you're looking for and decide where to post it based on which site's the most likely to give you that.